# Dynamics CRM Publishing Customizations - Multi Developers

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2013

In my company we are 5 developers who work on same organisation.

We used a single server with SQL and Dynamics CRM installed.

If two developers publish customizations at the same time, we need to restart IIS.

Do you have any suggestions to optimize SQL Server or IIS to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in the way CRM works, publishing will slow everything down and potentially lock the SQL server up.

Your options would to be to only publish when necessary, so you minimize your disruption to your developers. For stuff like form design, I would recommend not publishing, but, to preview the from to see your new changes.

Upgrading your servers with more memory and so on will help reduce the time taken to publish. Sorry this is not much help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

So if we don't want to freeze developers we need to have one organisation for each and export solution in a common Organisation.

Comment: @MarcOberlé I wouldn't recommend creating all the different organizations as your solutions may require components that the other developers may not have an so on. I also don't believe it will speed things up that much as your will presumably still be using the same server. I will say to only publish what you need to, i.e. the certain entity your working on instead of publishing all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing webresources, you can use this little hack [webresource proxy](https://github.com/qq1/webresourceproxy) as workaround. Basically, it just replaces the content of the webresource by the response of generic web server. You don't need to update and publish webresource anymore.